# IIS- multiple sites vs one site with multiple child applications

Tags: iis

What is the best approach when I have multiple websites on the same ip address
like:
mywebsite.com
crm.mywebsite.com 
api.mywebsite.com 
etc.. (5 sites in total)

Should I create 1 site on IIS (mywebsite.com) with 4 child apps (crm.mywebsite.com, api.mywebsite.com...)
or
create 5 different sites 
Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis I doubt the IIS documentation ever leads you to multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create according to your requirement. If you have multiple websites on the same ip address, then you can run Multiple Websites on the IP Address on IIS.

what you need to do is configure a Host Header for a Web Site, More information you can refer to this link: [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753195(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)